# In-approximability results in severely restricted graph classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness, apx

Longest path problem is not polynomial-time approximable to any constant factor in cubic Hamiltonian graphs (Longest path $\notin APX$ unless $P=NP$). I don't know if it remains in-approximable in cubic bipartite Hamiltonian graphs. Maximum independent set is not in $APX$ unless $P=NP$ but it is in $APX$ for cubic graphs. David Eppstein pointed out that it is $NP$-complete to find maximum clique in claw-free graphs and it is not clear to me if it is any easier to approximate than in general graphs.

- I'm interested in optimization problems that remains in-approximable in **severely restricted** classes of graphs (for instance, cubic planar bipartite graphs or trees of bounded degree).

A problem $L$ is In-approximable means that  $L \notin APX$. It is $NP$-hard to approximate to any constant factor in polynomial-time.

Comment: Here is the link to David's answer, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3338/graph-classes-in-which-clique-is-known-to-be-np-hard/3356#3356

Answer (score 7):

The labelled perfect matching problem, which consists in finding a perfect matching in an edge-coloured graph that uses the minimum number of colours, is not in APX for subcubic bipartite graphs (but it is $2$-approximable if the maximum degree is $2$ instead of $3$). See [Monnot](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~monnot/index_fichiers/Rairo_HardLM.pdf) for details.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for this interesting example, Does it remain in-approximable if the number of colors is bounded?

Comment: It seems to depend on how you bound them. [This other paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disopt.2010.02.003) answers your question positively in the case where "every colour appears in the graph at most $r$ times and $r$ is an increasing function of $n$". I don't know about other particular cases, but there may very well exist other such results.

Answer (score 7):

The Bandwidth problem remains NP-hard to approximate within any constant factor even when restricted to caterpillars (a special class of trees where all vertices of degree $>2$ lie on a path). This is shown by Dubey, Feige and Unger in ["Hardness results for approximating the bandwidth"](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~feige/mypapers/DubeyFeigeUnger.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

There are problems like **common subtree problem** remains NP-complete/hard and inapproximable within constant factors (in the case of common subtree problem, it is [inapproximable](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node168.html) within $n^{1/4-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$) even on trees, see [the post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/np-hard-problems-on-trees) by Shiva Kintali.

Answer (score 4):

The Group Steiner problem is $\Omega(\log^{2-\epsilon} n)$ hard on trees. The multicut problem is APX-hard on trees. The maximum integer flow problem is also APX-hard in capacitated trees.